# What does 'x' mean as the last letter in `src` attribute

Tags: javascript

In some projects I noticed that javascripts included into HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/score.js?x"></script>
```

What's mean last 'x' symbol?

Comment: That's a querystring.  It's probably used as a cachebuster.

Comment: Can also be used to pass variables to your script.

Answer (score 2):

It is a query string which may be used to pass variables to the script.

It will help to overcome cache problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would say the X is being used as a querystring fragment. Unless the server is depending on the fragment being there, it could possibly be used as a cache buster.

Essentially, by changing that X to a Y we could make the browser fetch a fresh copy. This is useful if you need to make sure users get a new copy of a file.

Of course, without talking to the author we are just guessing. Perhaps the server needs it there to properly build the file in the first place. Or maybe the javascript itself is using it.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not a symbol.** It is a piece of query string like on web scripts it would be something like `test.php?reload=true`

Such techniques might be helpful to overcome the caching problem as mentioned by SLaks on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to your javascript. 
It can be used to initiliaze variable or be used somewhere.

Take a look at this link http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html